# How can I solve the following issue when I run the command to build the Linux environment on GitBash: Python was not found, disable this shortcut

Tags: linux, github, embedded-linux, git-bash, openembedded

The following error message is displayed when I run the build environment on GitBash for Linux Poky file:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft store, or disable this shortcut from Settings>Manage  App Execution Aliases.
BitBake requires Python 3.8.0 or later as Python3.
```

In the execution alias, I disabled App installed Python.exe and enabled Python3.exe.
In the environment variables, I changed the path for system settings to Python and Python scripts.
GitBash shell recognise python version 3.12 when I ask for the version of python installed.

However the same error message is shown when I try running the build environment command in the Gitbash power shell

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** which represent textual information. Instead, we expect that information to be presented as **text**. Please, (re-)read [ask] and [edit] the question post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run `python3 --version`?

Poky should work in WSL2, but *not* WSL1 and *not* a Windows terminal. If there are `.exe` files involved then you're not in WSL2.

Comment: It returns  Python 3.12.2

Comment: Not a Win terminal.That is why I used Unix-like terminal called Gitbash. I am not using WSL. I am building a customized distribution from the source code of Yocto Project.

Comment: Yocto needs to build on Linux.  A "unix-like" environment isn't sufficient, on Windows you need to use WSL2.